# Highstock chart offsets dates for no reason

Tags: date, highcharts

I'm having trouble with highstock.js

For no apparent reason it seems to offset the dates halfway though when it has generated the chart.

It occurs because the date 25 march is showed twice in the chart with a value 0 for it's second entry on the x-axis. There is no data to support this second erroneously date entry.

I've made a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DZGz7/

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
chart: {
            renderTo: 'containerchart',
            alignTicks: false
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 0
        },
        title: {
            text: 'New Members'
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false
        },
        xAxis: {
               minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
        },
        plotOptions:{
           line:{
              dataGrouping:{enabled:false}
           }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'New Members',
            data: ([
[1322611200000,3],[1322697600000,40],[1322784000000,21],[1322870400000,14],[1322956800000,5],     [1323043200000,6],[1323129600000,11],[1323216000000,14],[1323302400000,16],[1323388800000,11],[1323475200000,9],[1323561600000,8],[1323648000000,8],[1323734400000,3],[1323820800000,5],[1323907200000,5],[1323993600000,4],[1324080000000,4],[1324166400000,5],[1324252800000,3],[1324339200000,5],[1324425600000,4],[1324512000000,5],[1324598400000,0],[1324684800000,1],[1324771200000,1],[1324857600000,2],[1324944000000,9],[1325030400000,4],[1325116800000,5],[1325203200000,9],[1325289600000,0],[1325376000000,6],[1325462400000,4],[1325548800000,3],[1325635200000,4],[1325721600000,6],[1325808000000,8],[1325894400000,4],[1325980800000,4],[1326067200000,6],[1326153600000,6],[1326240000000,2],[1326326400000,6],[1326412800000,5],[1326499200000,3],[1326585600000,3],[1326672000000,5],[1326758400000,5],[1326844800000,1],[1326931200000,9],[1327017600000,11],[1327104000000,6],[1327190400000,0],[1327276800000,2],[1327363200000,4],[1327449600000,4],[1327536000000,5],[1327622400000,3],[1327708800000,5],[1327795200000,8],[1327881600000,3],[1327968000000,6],[1328054400000,3],[1328140800000,2],[1328227200000,2],[1328313600000,3],[1328400000000,4],[1328486400000,0],[1328572800000,2],[1328659200000,3],[1328745600000,8],[1328832000000,2],[1328918400000,5],[1329004800000,2],[1329091200000,2],[1329177600000,10],[1329264000000,5],[1329350400000,2],[1329436800000,3],[1329523200000,4],[1329609600000,0],[1329696000000,2],[1329782400000,13],[1329868800000,5],[1329955200000,6],[1330041600000,6],[1330128000000,4],[1330214400000,5],[1330300800000,3],[1330387200000,5],[1330473600000,3],[1330560000000,2],[1330646400000,5],[1330732800000,2],[1330819200000,8],[1330905600000,1],[1330992000000,3],[1331078400000,3],[1331164800000,3],[1331251200000,8],[1331337600000,5],[1331424000000,3],[1331510400000,2],[1331596800000,2],[1331683200000,3],[1331769600000,1],[1331856000000,6],[1331942400000,1],[1332028800000,3],[1332115200000,2],[1332201600000,3],[1332288000000,6],[1332374400000,2],[1332460800000,4],[1332547200000,2],[1332633600000,7],[1332716400000,0],[1332802800000,5],[1332889200000,1],[1332975600000,4],[1333062000000,4],[1333148400000,1],[1333234800000,8],[1333321200000,1],[1333407600000,4],[1333494000000,3],[1333580400000,3],[1333666800000,4],[1333753200000,1]
])
}]
});
```

(zoom in around march 25 and see the data offset begins)

The dates correspond to the right data up until March 25 2012 after that it is shifted 1 day. You will be able to see the offset happening, by comparing the tooltip data to the x-axis label.
Obviously this seems like a problem in the data loaded into the graph, But I've checked it over and the next date it should display is March 26. The data seems just fine.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://api.Highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC:

> useUTC: Boolean
>
> Whether to use UTC time for axis scaling, tickmark
> placement and time display in Highcharts.dateFormat.
>
> Advantages of
> using UTC is that the time displays equally regardless of the user
> agent's time zone settings. Local time can be used when the data is
> loaded in real time or when correct Daylight Saving Time transitions
> are required. Defaults to true.

Therefore, if you want your chart to show in the Browser's local time, you need to take action as follows in your javascript:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

Presumably, this should be set before you create your chart.

Answer (score 1):

UTC had to be turned off, then it works.

```
global:{
    useUTC: false
}
```